# Can you insert a link from within the double brackets in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Lets say that I have this code in my html:

```
{{text}}
```

Now, lets say that "text" is actually an address. Is there a way to make the displayed value of text clickable as if there was a "a href=" tag but without modifying the html file? In other words, is there a way to generate the "a href=" tag effect from within angularjs?

EDIT: I'm gonna assume the downvote is from someone that thinks I want to do something like:

```
<a ng-href={{text}}>
```

This is not the case. Assume there is no tags at all. Just {{text}}.

Comment: Why are you trying to replicate HTML without actual HTML?

Comment: @yvesmancera  I tried adding the a href="link" tag inside the text value but that didn't generate a link as expected. Searched around on google but I can only find info on having the html file already tagged to handle the possibility of text being an address (which is not what I need).

Comment: @ryanyuyu Lets just say that it would really facilitate my life if I could this instead of having to adapt the html file.

Comment: sounds like a simple css fix if all you are asking for is how  to make the text look like a link. Question is a bit hard to interpret and overall objective isn't clear at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing:

```
<div>{{text}}</div>
```

you should do this :

```
<div ng-bind-html="text"></div>
```

and inject $sce into your controller, then do this :

```
$scope.text = $sce.trustAsHtml(someHtmlVar);
```

and it will inject your HTML code from the "text" model, inside the div